# Python pandas dataframe skipping lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i have this loop that adds a string to a dataframe. This works fine. However, when I try to add a number in the second column, it skips lines (as you can see in the output).`    while counter < 50:

```
    #gets just the subreddit name
    e = str(elem[counter].get_attribute("href"))
    e = e.replace("https://www.reddit.com/r/", "")
    e = e[:-1]

   #e is the subreddit string

    df = df.append({'Subreddit': e}, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.append({'Appearances': 1 }, ignore_index=True)

    print(e)
    counter = counter + 2

print(df)`
```

output -

```
               Subreddit Appearances
0              worldnews         NaN
1                    NaN           1
2                   pics         NaN
3                    NaN           1
4                    aww         NaN
5                    NaN           1
6         RedditInReddit         NaN
```

I know it has something to do with the way I am looping but I can't seem to understand what. Also I have to increment by 2 each time because the subreddits appear twice on the page, and i only need to grab 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) appends a row each time. You can include 2 keys in your dictionary to add one row for each iteration:

```
df = df.append({'Subreddit': e, 'Appearances': 1}, ignore_index=True)
```

But you should never have to use `pd.DataFrame.append` in a loop this way. This will be inefficient as `pd.DataFrame.append` is expensive versus `list.append` due to additional copy operations.

Instead, you can build a list of lists and call `pd.DataFrame.append` once. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
L = []
for _ in some_iterable:
    L.append([e, 1])

to_append = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Subreddit', 'Appearances'])
df = df.append(to_append, ignore_index=True)
```